# Removing searching results

Tags: web, search, resultset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r32vB.jpg)
How to remove these searching results from any website?

I tried to delete the data from the website and cookies

Comment: This sounds off-topic. Even if it's on-topic, you need to say what browser you're on. This feature looks like it is "autofill". Please at least [edit] to say what browser you are using.

Comment: If you're using chrome, there's a very similar question here: [How to delete specific autofill entries from Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/q/1289097/1749748)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To delete a single result**

Focus on the result (by hovering over with the mouse or tabbing onto it) and press the `Delete` key.

**To delete all results**

Follow the instructions for your particular browser: https://support.iclasspro.com/hc/en-us/articles/218569268-How-Do-I-Disable-or-Clear-AutoFill-AutoComplete-Information-

Copying steps for Chrome below (since it covers approx 2/3rds of users as of 2022):

> **Clearing Autofill Data in Chrome**
>
> 1. Click the Chrome menu icon. (Three dots at top right of screen.)
> 2. Click on History, then click on History again in the menu that appears.
> 3. Select Clear browsing data. (Alternatively, you can press CTRL+SHIFT+DEL on your keyboard to bypass steps 1-3.)
> 4. If it is not already selected, click on the "Advanced" tab.
> 5. At the top, choose “All Time” option to clear all saved data.
> 6. Make sure that the “Autofill Form Data” option is checked. If you wish to clear "Passwords and other sign-in data", be sure to check
>    that option as well.
> 7. Click "Clear Data."